# Installation of tun module for CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, centos, vps

I'm trying to use ZeroTier to create a VPN and use it on a VPS. This VPS has a CentOS 7 installation.
I installed ZeroTier and could join the network, but it gives me a PORT_ERROR, and I cannot ping the VPS through the Managed IPs.

I tried to restart ZeroTier and checked the status, and it gave me the following errors:

```
zerotier-one[1496]: /usr/sbin/zerotier-one: WARNING: failed to drop privileges (kernel may not support required prctl features), running as root

zerotier-one[1496]: ERROR: unable to configure virtual network port: could not open TUN/TAP device: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to check for the tun module, and it turns out it wasn't loaded, but not only that, it isn't installed either (I checked with `lsmod | grep tun`, then used `modprobe tun` to try to load it, and checked again but there was nothing running)

I've tried installing the `net-tools` package and creating the tun module and device myself, and rebooting the VPS afterwards, but I haven't been able to solve this issue. 
I've also searched on how to install the module but I couldn't find any solution.
What I found in many places was that maybe the problem is that the VPS provider has to enable that module for us.

Is there any way I can install the module myself, apart from what I've already tried, or do I have to ask the provider?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know if this is a "full virtualization" VPS (KVM, Xen, HyperV) or if it's a container only (OpenVZ, LXC)? Cheapest ones tend to be the latter. Does /proc have a "user_beancounters" file? Does `lsblk`, `lsblk -S` show real devices like sda/vda?

Comment: @grawity I think it's a container, using OpenVZ! It's supposedly a cheap one, so it must be.
**EDIT** (sorry, used enter accidentally): /proc doesn't have a file with that name, and `lsblk` & `lsblk -S` doesn't show anything.

Comment: If lsblk shows nothing, it's probably OpenVZ. Double-check using `sudo systemd-detect-virt`?

Comment: @grawity checked and it is indeed OpenVZ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server uses OpenVZ, it is not a complete "virtual server"; it works more like a Docker or LXC container. The important bit being that **it doesn't have its own kernel** – all "VPSes" hosted on the same physical machine share the same kernel. This means you cannot install any modules, you only get what features the host system has loaded.

Many OpenVZ hosts do provide 'tun' device support; sometimes it is an option you need to enable through the server's control panel (WHM or whatever), or by contacting support (though that would be a bit unusual).

But if the host doesn't support 'tun' devices, you don't have any options short of going elsewhere (preferably to a KVM/Xen-based VPS – these do vary in where they load the OS kernel from, but nearly all support using your own kernel, and nearly all support tun by default).

Comment: Thank you a lot for all your help! I'll check if I can activate it on the control panel.